# Obtaining continuous probability inequality from discrete one?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is probably a silly question that I should know how to answer.

The question is interesting by its own right but motivated from a question in the book the probabilistic method, where we need to prove that

$ (P(|X-Y|\leq2))\leq 3(P(|X-Y|\leq1)$

For any $2$ discrete random variables $X,Y$ that are distributed identically.

I have proved this for discrete ones, and it seems plausible that this means it should hold for any random variables. How do I move from the discrete to the continuous?

Please don't post any solution to the exercise above, I'm just interestedin being able to use apprxomations to transfer things about discrete variables to arbitary one (if it's even true that this can be done).

Some thoughts of my own:

WLOG we can assume our arbitrary random variables $Z,W$ are bounded, because we can cut them far enough (where $P(z>r)<\epsilon$ where we would take $\epsilon$ by assuming by contradiction that the inequality isn't true and messing with that).

Now I know that any measureable function can be approximated by step functions uniformly assuming it is bounded, and again this means this means it's enough to show that we can move from discrete to step functions by assuming by contradiction and taking an appropriate $\epsilon$ (I'm avoiding the boring details), although sadly this seems to work only in this case where I'd want something more general.

Probably with a bit of thought I can then approximate those step functions, but I'm annoyed at how this is not general at all. Is there a more systematic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n=[nX]/n$ and similarly $Y_n=[nY]/n$. Since $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are discrete, we have 
$$
\Pr(|X_n-Y_n|\leq 2)\leq 3\Pr(|X_n-Y_n|\leq 1).
$$
For every $\epsilon>0$, and $n>4\epsilon^{-1}$, 
$$\Pr(|X_{n}-Y_{n}|\leq 2) \geq \Pr(|X-Y|\leq 2- \epsilon)$$
and 
$$\Pr(|X_{n}-Y_{n}|\leq 1) \leq \Pr(|X-Y|\leq 1+ \epsilon).$$
It follows that 
$$
\Pr(|X-Y|<2)\leq 3\Pr(|X-Y|\leq 1).
$$
Applying this to the pair $(a^{-1}X,a^{-1}Y)$ yields
$$
\Pr(|X-Y|<2a)\leq 3\Pr(|X-Y|\leq a),
$$
for every $a>1$. Letting $a\downarrow 1$ concludes the proof.

Comment: That works wonderfully, thanks. Just to make sure, this is the typically used way to move from discrete to continous? (also why the $2^n$ and not just $n$ edit?)

Comment: This is quite typical. When you cannot assume the r.v. are bounded you have to work a bit harder, but not much harder.

Comment: Edit: I simplified the answer

Comment: Cool. One last thing, if I'm not mistakes you're assuming the probability $|X-Y|=a$ is $0$ for this to work right? So what I should do more generally is decompose the variables into their continous and disrete part?

Comment: I don't think you need to do that. You can, instead look at $\Pr(|X-Y|<a)$. Then, you let $a\uparrow 2$ on the LHS, and $a\downarrow 1$ on the RHS.

Comment: But I can't do that, since I don't know the inequality if I don't take $1,2$ (or something like $r,2r$, which what you're sayin'g won't allow me to do).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65075/discussion-between-ron-and-andy).

Comment: Edit: complete answer